# is there compiler option that sets the warnings/errors to match those common at the time when the code was written?

Tags: gcc, llvm, llvm-clang, gcc-warning, legacy-code

Code written 20 years ago often won't compile with *today's* `-Wall`.

Is there a record of default settings for say GCC from 1997, or other years?

And I know I can turn off individual error/warnings in GCC.

Comment: How about `-ansi`, `-c90` and [similar](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html)?

Comment: that might be the only option.  But it's hard to tell what standard was used for old code if the source doesn't come with a Makefile or similar; like when there's only a few functions or single isolated source file.